# Virtuemart Database

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am working on an android application to make some website available on mobile to browse.
The thing is Virtuemart tables are too many to read and i need this to be quick and quite east so i can take a JSON object to from the db.
what i need in specific is to read the categories, then each category products with details images etc...
i tried to read the tables and make select statements but still cant find what i need.
I can code the PHP and the SQL statements but the tables are too much i would appreciate any help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be far more specific, or supply some code that didn't work, and what is wrong with it.

Comment: thanks i got this working by just reading the whole tables and database .
i thought there is some ready made function to read that data :)